# how to calculate statistic significance for two list in an ab test by using python

Tags: python, list

I made an A/B test, I have data as following:

```
  control_conversion  test_conversion 
day1  100                 101         
day3  140                 200
day5  200                 320
day7  400                 800
```

Control and test group have 1000 traffic
so the conversion rate would be:

```
  control_conversion  test_conversion  
day1  0.10                0.10  
day3  0.14                0.20
day5  0.20                0.32
day7  0.40                0.80
```

I want to use python to calculate the statistic significance for 
day1, day3, day5, day7 for control and test.

So I would need to make two list:

```
control = [0.1, 0.14, 0.20, 0.40]
test = [0.1,0.2,0.32,0.8]
```

How can I calculate four p value for the two list?

like what I want to see is a list of p values

pvalue =[0.1, 0.2, 0,1,0.2,0.1]

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty, assuming control and test hold the same number of items:

```
control = [0.1, 0.14, 0.20, 0.40]
test = [0.1,0.2,0.32,0.8]

for idx in range(len(control)):
    val_co = control[idx]
    val_te = test[idx]
    # do whatever you want to do with val_co and val_te
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [binomial test function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom_test.html) in SciPy

```
from scipy.stats import binom_test
n = 1000

control = [100, 140,200,400]
test = [101,200,320,800]
pvals = []
for idx in range(len(control)):
    pvals.append(binom_test(test[idx],n=n, p=control[idx]/n))

print(pvals)

[0.9160130517865064, 1.8593423831091924e-07, 4.004795877115897e-19, 1.644604962019165e-147]
```

(I just did a [basic 101 blog post](https://pygot.wordpress.com/2018/06/28/hypothesis-testing-in-python/) on this)